# Cell on table view broken UI

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've a problem with custom cell on UITableView. 
Almost cell in table view work well. However, I have one cell can not show text like image. It has only occurred on iOS 8  [image]

Could you help me to solve this problem. You will save time of my life. Thanks.

Comment: What have you done in order to resolve it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Common mistakes:

1. set `cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0`
2. set `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`
3. dont fix the height of your label, while giving constraints.
4. dont implement `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat`

I would recommend you to go through this tutorial, for better clarity.

http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/